# Monodevelop C++ debugging issue

Tags: c++, debugging, monodevelop, fedora, xterm

I'm running Fedora 20 (GNOME) and attempting to using monodevelop for my C++ class.  I have the gbd add-on installed and xterm. When I attempt to debug it throws the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Console could not be created.
>     at MonoDevelop.Debugger.Gdb.GdbSession.OnRun (Mono.Debugging.Client.DebuggerStartInfo startInfo) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Mono.Debugging.Client.DebuggerSession+c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in :0

I found this about my issue: https://github.com/aBothe/Mono-D/issues/396

A solution seems to be either removing gnome-terminal or making sure xterm isn't a symbolic link to another terminal. I'd rather preform the latter, but I'm not sure how to complete that solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to a recent gnome-terminal change. Recent gnome-terminal no longer accepts the --disable-factory argument.

Install the xterm package, then in a gnome-terminal session do the following:

```
$ unset GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID 
$ monodevelop
```

This will cause monodevelop to use xterm as its external terminal and all should be well.

Comment: Does this need to be ran every time?

Comment: @This is still happening, I just tried to debug with Monodevelop-opt version 5.4 on Debian 7 "KDE".

Comment: Seconded... still happening. Monodevelop 5.4

Comment: @user2461522, yours is the best answer, it worked for me,  NonoDevelop 5.10.  Thanks,

Comment: How to avoid to run everytime?